# How to add a new key value pair to Consul using Ansible consul_kv?

Tags: ansible, yaml, consul

I have a new key, value pair which I'd like to add to a remote consul. With the current setup, values are updated for an existing key. But new key, value pairs are not added.
This is the setup I have :

```
- name: default values to consul
  include_vars:
    file: consul_values.yml
    name: default

- name: populate default values into consul
  consul_kv:
    key: "{{ item.key }}"
    value: "{{ item.value }}"
    recurse: true
    host: "{{ consul_url }}"
    port: "{{ consul_port }}"
    scheme: "{{ consul_scheme }}"
  with_dict: "{{ default }}"
```

Am I missing anything here? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This module works as expected. There was a different issue elsewhere due to which I had to post this here